# Different behavior between the location of static assert in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a CRTP in C++ and use `static_assert` to see whether derived class has implemented the specific method. But I find that different locations of `static_assert` will have different outputs.

The first one:

```
template <typename, typename T>
struct has_f
{
    static_assert(
        std::integral_constant<T, false>::value,
        "Second template parameter needs to be of function type.");
};
template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_f<C, Ret(Args...)>
{
private:
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T *)
        -> typename std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<T>().f(std::declval<Args>()...)),
            Ret>::type;
    template <typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);
    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};

// T must have a method called f
template <class Derived>
class BaseCRTP
{

public:
    int f(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::cout << "not optimized" << std::endl;
        static_assert(has_f<Derived, int(const std::string &)>::value, "Derived must have a method called f");
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->f(s);
    }

    void test()
    {
        f("Fsafas");
    }
};

class Derived : public BaseCRTP<Derived>
{
public:
    int f(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::f()" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.test();
    return 0;
}
```

This will compile peacefully and print two lines.

The second one:

```
template <typename, typename T>
struct has_f
{
    static_assert(
        std::integral_constant<T, false>::value,
        "Second template parameter needs to be of function type.");
};
template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_f<C, Ret(Args...)>
{
private:
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T *)
        -> typename std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<T>().f(std::declval<Args>()...)),
            Ret>::type;
    template <typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);
    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};

// T must have a method called f
template <class Derived>
class BaseCRTP
{

public:
    int f(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::cout << "not optimized" << std::endl;
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->f(s);
    }

    static_assert(has_f<Derived, int(const std::string &)>::value, "Derived must have a method called f");

    void test()
    {
        f("Fsafas");
    }
};

class Derived : public BaseCRTP<Derived>
{
public:
    int f(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::f()" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.test();
    return 0;
}
```

This version will not compile and give me a weird message:

```
crtp.cc:76:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'has_f<Derived, int (const std::string &)>::value' "Derived must have a method called f"
    static_assert(has_f<Derived, int(const std::string &)>::value, "Derived must have a method called f");
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
crtp.cc:84:24: note: in instantiation of template class 'BaseCRTP<Derived>' requested here
class Derived : public BaseCRTP<Derived>
```

Very confused and wish I can get some insights here.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Derived` is an incomplete type when you put the `static_assert` in the body of the definition of `BaseCRTP`.

Also note that the check in your first version would accept a `Derived` without a definition of `int f(const std::string &s)` in the derived class since it *is* defined in `BaseCRTP`. This means that when `Derived` is a complete type, it *will* have an `int f(const std::string &s)` member function.